# Move data from parent account to child account

Tags: ipad, apple-id, data-transfer, family-sharing

My kid has used my Apple ID for his iPad for several years while I've been on Android phones. I've recently moved back to Apple and realize we can not share the same account anymore as images etc. gets very mixed up.

I´ve created a child account for him under the Family sharing option, and my questions are:
If I set up his iPad with his new child account, will he:

- Be able to download all previously purchased apps / games for free?
- Be able to get his photos into his gallery?
- Maintain the progress from games?
- Maintain progress, files etc. from apps for school such as Showbie and Book Creator?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Apps/games can be redownloaded through the purchased screen in AppStore, Photos needs to be transferred manually, some games store progress on device (no issue with different Apple-ID's), other support syncing accounts with services such as Facebook, while some may be tied to your iCloud/GameCenter sub account, and is therefore non transferable, and a bunch supports a combination of the above.

Answer (score 1):

Purchases, activity, and app/game progress are tied to an Apple ID.  In this case, they're tied to your Apple ID and there's no way to transfer this to a different Apple ID (your child's ID).

Some apps allow family sharing and some don't.  Because you've enabled that feature, your child will be able to access for free any apps you've already purchased.  In-app purchases will not be accessible by your child.

The activity/progress made on those apps under your ID will not be transferred to your child.  As of today, there's no way to transfer that that info.

Your child's account will be setup as a brand new account.  See [Apple's Family Sharing](https://www.apple.com/family-sharing/) site for more info.

Comment: @ThomasRussArnestad Did this answer work for you?